# How can I configure HTTP Response Headers in a Struts2 Interceptor?

Tags: java, struts2, http-headers, httpresponse, struts2-interceptors

We currently have a java web application in the middle of migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2. We would like to configure `X-Frame-Options` and `Content-Security-Policy` headers for all our Struts 2 actions. We have a lot of actions and I want to avoid modifying them all separately if at all possible.

the idea I currently have is the following interceptor which would be added to the default stack:

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;    
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;    
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class HttpHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation Invocation) throws Exception {
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        response.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri REDACTED");
        response.addHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri REDACTED");
        return Invocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

I tried the above, and it does not work, it does not set the headers.

What changes do I need to make to fix this interceptor? Is it even possible to change response headers in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to get the the response (and the request) inside an Interceptor is through the `InvocationContext`, instead that through the `ServletActionContext`:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation Invocation) throws Exception {

    final ActionContext ac = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ac.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RE‌​SPONSE);
    //HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    response.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri REDACTED");
    response.addHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri REDACTED");
    return Invocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: It's equivalent way to get the response.

Comment: I don't know why, but I remember it behaves differently; it happened to me in the past, to other people, and to OP. I'd appreciate to learn more about this, though. Anyone ?